# cassandra read timeout in java butruns well on cqlsh

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I'm runnig a select query on cassandra in java.It return read timeout exception.The problem is that is doen not produce an error in cqlsh.So the problem is in the code i guess.I'm using flink to connect to cassandra.Also i think that maybe the problem is that in cqlsh i need to hit enter the get more results.Maybe that's the cause for stopping the drive to read through all the result.Also when i use limit 100 it runs well.I have changed the cassandra.yaml read configuration but nothing changed.

```java
ClusterBuilder cb = new ClusterBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
                return builder.withPort(9042).addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                        .withSocketOptions(new SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(60000).setKeepAlive(true).setReuseAddress(true))
                         .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy())
                        .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(500L))
                        .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE))
                        .build();
            }
        };

        CassandraInputFormat<Tuple1<ProfileAlternative>> cassandraInputFormat = new CassandraInputFormat("SELECT toJson(profilealternative) FROM profiles.profile where skills contains 'Financial Sector'  ", cb);

        cassandraInputFormat.configure(null);
        cassandraInputFormat.open(null);

        Tuple1<ProfileAlternative> testOutputTuple = new Tuple1();

        while (!cassandraInputFormat.reachedEnd()) {
            cassandraInputFormat.nextRecord(testOutputTuple);
            System.out.println(testOutputTuple.f0);
        }
```

Comment: Can you try your query in cqlsh with manually put big limit for testing? Maybe the issue is on server side.

Comment: i solved the issue by deleting the logs files and deleting other tables that i didn't need.Thanks tho @SergeHarnyk